# Linking error after update HDF5 library

Tags: cmake, hdf5

My system: Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa HDF5 updated from 7 Version: 1.8.16, C++ program

`cmake` finds the libraries, but executing `make` throws lots of errors like this:

```
../isf/libISF.so: Nicht definierter Verweis auf H5::DataSet::read(std::string&, H5::DataType const&, H5::DataSpace const&, H5::DataSpace const&, H5::DSetMemXferPropList const&) const'
```

In `cmake` I linked the same Libraries as before:

```
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(ISF
        ${HDF5_LIBRARIES}
        "libhdf5_hl_cpp.so")
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you deleted the CMakeCache.txt? Probably it is an outdated version.

Comment: It seems that you are linking to libISF.so, and that this library has some unresolved symbols. You should also link to the libraries containing the missing definition. Said in other words, there's another library you are not linking to where H5::DataSet::read is defined. If you call `make VERBOSE=1` you will see the exact command line passed to your compiler/linker, so that you can check all needed libraries are listed.